# How to fix my array in node.js and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, forms, mongodb, mongoose

My array in my MongoDB is not being structured the way I want it to be. I am using node.js, Express, and Mongoose.

Here is my schema:

```
var fruitSchema = new schema ({
    fruitName: {type: String},
    priceArray: {type: Array}
});
```

Here is part of the code that pushes new priceArray items:

```
Fruit.findOneAndUpdate({fruitName: req.body.fruitName},
            {
            $push: {
                priceArray: {
                    price: req.body.price,
                    description: req.body.description
                }
            }
        }
```

And here is the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/fruit">
<div class='form-group'>
    <label for="fruitName">Fruit Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fruitName" id="fruitName"/>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="price0">Price</label>
    <input type="text" name="price[0]" id="price0"/>

    <label for="description0">Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="description[0]" id="description0"/>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="price1">Price</label>
    <input type="text" name="price[1]" id="price1"/>

    <label for="description1">Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="description[1]" id="description1"/>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

So what's all this saying? Basically, a user can enter a name of a fruit, and then they would enter the **price** of the fruit, and give a **description**. So the **'price'** and **'description'** pieces are always together. The form allows for multiple inputs of price/description pairs (the example form I've posted here allows for 2 pairs, but the real form allows for unlimited pairs).

In my MongoDB, this is how the above code inserts the form data:

```
{
"fruitName" : "test fruit",
"priceArray" : [ 
    {
        "price" : [ 
            "$2.00", 
            "$3.00"
        ],
        "description" : [ 
            "Good", 
            "Bad"
        ]
    }
```

Here is how I **want** it to look like:

```
{
"fruitName" : "test fruit",
"priceArray" : [ 
    {
        "price" : "$2.00"
        "description: "Good" 
    }
    {
        "price" : "$3.00"
        "description" : "Bad"
    }
    ]
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A) See this :

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

& Declare Schema as :

```
var fruitSchema = new schema ({
    fruitName: {type: String},
    priceArray: [{
    price: String,
    description: String
     }]
});
```

B) 
See your req.body in logs. You will have to process req.body.price & description
because they are separate arrays . So you need to change the findOne&update accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, that will work when submitting one 'price' and one 'description' at a time. But when you try to send two 'price' and 'description' inputs together, you get the result I showed above (the result I don't want).